# playing audio in html using <audio>

Tags: html, audio, background, mp3

I am a newbie writing my first webpage.

Today I'm trying to put a background music on it and for it I wrote this:

```
</style>
</head>
<audio src = "cookingMusic.mp3" autoplay></audio>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="heading">
```

(the part after also omitted)

So, I put the audio tag in-between the head and body. I tried several different places too. All failed to generate any audio. The `cookingMusic.mp3` file is on my computer desktop in the same folder with my HTML webpage document. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi everyone now I have a burning question.  It worked, but I am now trying to make the same change on Github(that's just where I keep my practice webpage), but the repository won't take mp3 files as a new issue (that's the only way I know and where I put my images).  How can I embed the audio in this case?

Comment: You need to use Git if you want to add a file repo.  Install Git, clone your repo locally, put the file into the appropriate directory, use `git add`, then `git commit -a -m "Adding some MP3 files"`, and then push using something like `git push -u origin master`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, everyone, it worked!

Because I jump between Chinese and English, I think my quotation marks were screwed up again.  I changed them and got the music.

Answer (score 0):

All other answers are fine but if you don't want other people to see your audio player then use this:

```html
<audio loop autoplay>
<source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/horse.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>
```

`Loop` is optional. Just put this anywhere inside your body tag and it's gonna work fine.

Answer (score -1):

```html
<audio preload="auto" autoplay="autoplay">
    <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/>
</audio>
```

Above code will be working fine with online audio URL/path.
Check your audio path and put complete relative path with an audio name in src tag.